# Proper way to wait for a function to finish or data to load before rendering in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react code that pulls some data from an api and outputs it. In `result['track_list']` I receive a list of tracks with a timestamp and in `aggTrackList()` I am aggregating the data into key value pair based on the day/month/year then displaying that aggregated data in a Card component I created.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [trackList, settracks] = useState([]);
  const [sortby, setSortby] = useState("day");
  const [sortedList, setSortedList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    aggTrackList();
  }, [sortby]);
  
  const aggTrackList = () => {
    setSortedList([]);
    let sortedObj = {};
    switch (sortby) {
      case "day":
        trackList.forEach((track) => {
          let dayVal = new Date(track[3]).toDateString();
          dayVal in sortedObj
            ? sortedObj[dayVal].push(track)
            : (sortedObj[dayVal] = [track]);
        });
        setSortedList(sortedObj);
        break;
      case "month":
        trackList.forEach((track) => {
          let monthVal = new Date(track[3]).toDateString().split(" ");
          let monthYear = monthVal[1] + monthVal[3];
          monthYear in sortedObj
            ? sortedObj[monthYear].push(track)
            : (sortedObj[monthYear] = [track]);
        });
        setSortedList(sortedObj);
        break;
      case "year":
        trackList.forEach((track) => {
          let yearVal = new Date(track[3]).toDateString().split(" ");
          let year = yearVal[3];
          year in sortedObj
            ? sortedObj[year].push(track)
            : (sortedObj[year] = [track]);
        });
        setSortedList(sortedObj);
        break;
    }
  };

  const getUserTracks = (username) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost/my/api/${username}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          settracks(result["tracks_played"]);
          aggTrackList();
          setIsLoaded(true);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SortMenu
        setSort={(selected) => {
          setSortby(selected);
        }}
      />
      <UserForm onSubmit={getUserTracks} />
      <div className="trackList">
        {isLoaded ? (
          Object.entries(sortedList).map(([day, track]) => (
            <Card
              className="card"
              displayMode={sortby}
              key={day}
              timestamp={day}
              content={track}
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          <div>...</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The issue I am having is when `UserForm` is submitted and receives the data. The Card elements do not render unless I update the `sortby` state by clicking on one of the sortmenu options after the data has loaded. How can I get the data to show automatically after it has been loaded?

I'm creating this project to learn React so if something can be done better or if I am doing things wrong, please let me know.

Thanks.

Edit:
My code on codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-minsky-bjko8?file=/src/App.js with sample data from my API.

Comment: Would you mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/ . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: @decpk [Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-minsky-bjko8?file=/src/App.js) I put it all in one file and replaced the fetch with small subset of data. It has the same behaviour. enter anything in the form and no data will load unless you click on month or year.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in two ways:

1. In a blocking way using `useLayoutEffect` hook. Refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect).
2. In a non-blocking way using `useEffect` hook. Refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

### 1. `useLayoutEffect`

The thing to note here is that the function passed in the hook is executed first and the component is rendered.

1. Make the API call inside `useLayoutEffect` and then set the data once you obtain the response from the API. Where the data can initially be

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
```

The JSX must appropriately handle all the cases of different responses from the server.

### 2. `useEffect`

The thing to note here is that this function runs after the component has been rendered.

1. Make the API call inside the `useEffect` hook. Once the data is obtained, set the state variable accordingly.

Here your jsx can be something like

```
{
    data === null ? (
     <Loader />
       ) : data.length > 0 ? (
          <Table data={data} />
       ) : (
          <NoDataPlaceholder />
       )
}
```

Here I am assuming the data is a list of objects. but appropriate conditions can be used for any other format. Here while the data is being fetched using the API call made inside `useEffect`, the user will see a loading animation. Once the data is obtained, the user will be shown the data. In case the data is empty, the user will be show appropriate placeholder message.